# Why I can't create a file with ansible by accordding to the ansible-doc?

Tags: ansible

Below is the error information:

> ansible-file is absent, cannot continue, path:/webdev

I created a file with the following code:

```yaml
---

- name: create webfile

  hosts: dev

  tasks:
         - file:
                path: /webdev
                group: webdev
                mode: '2775'
```

But it can't create the file while the official example is:

```yaml
- name: Change file ownership, group and permissions
  file:
    path: /etc/foo.conf
    owner: foo
    group: foo
    mode: '0644'
```

My code didn't raise any error about who the file belongs to, so I think the error is raised because I don't have the `owner` entry.

Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: Do you wish to a create a file? If so, try the copy or template module. I think the file module can only be used to modify state of an existing file.

Comment: Hi Jie welcome to SO. I believe you may be looking for [`state: touch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-state)

Comment: @Parag Doke, thank you for your advice. I did as what mdaniel said and I fixed it. I will ansible-doc the two modules to learn how to create file with them.

Comment: @mdaniel I followed what you said and fixed it, which made me pleasure,hahaha, but there is still a confusion in my mind that is why the offcial example does not have the entry?

Comment: @Jie because this task is doing exactly what the name says: _Change file ownership, group and permissions_, so, it is changing those on an **existing** file.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, Thank you!(*^_^*) Now I understand why it can't create a file with your  help.(*^_^*)